# User Defined Fields PHP Mysql

Tags: mysql, field, database-schema, defined

I am currently building a small crm application.  I need each user to be able to define their own custom fields.  I am currently building this crm using php and mysql.

Example:  I have a "customer" table which has the standard fields: name, phone, address, email, etc.  But i want to allow the user (unique session) to add fields that are custom to his/her business which are only accessible to him (not other users).  I then want these custom fields to function just like all the other fields in the table (ability to search, send and received data).  I am hoping i can accomplish this in mysql and php but am open to any technology or solution that is considered best practice.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Look up the [Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) model and good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Matt H: Is this method considered AEV or just standard relational db?

So because i will have many users in many dif industries that will want to add their own custom fields to a number of different tables (contacts, transactions, events, etc) i am assuming that i would need the customfield table to have a user_fk/id or company fk/id, a related table fk/id, an id, and a field name?  Am i on the right track?  Then in the need to create a 2nd table to hold the data for each custom field buy having a customfield fk/id, customer fk/id, id and a data field to hold the actual data.  Is this correct?

Ok so once i build those two additional tables how do I add them to the contacts table so it looks like one big table for the user, instead of the 3 tables?

Thanks again for you help.

**Answer**

after much research i have found that most people who wish to accomplish this are using document databases not relational databases.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done by creating a table called "customfields" with the elements "id, fieldname, company_id", then another table that would associate those custom fields with data, eg "customercustomdata: id, customfields_id, customer_id". Associate "ownership" of a field the same way

To create a new custom field, "insert into customfields (fieldname,company_id) values ('Birthday',companyid);"

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you view my answer posted below, i had to put it down there because of space.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for all the comments.  Is there an easier way to do this in the table.  For example just add 10-20 blank columns to the contacts table and some how let the user define them?  If so how would i let the user define them?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's not an uncommon way to do it. However, it sounds like each company/user can define the description of what the column is. You would be extremely limited if you only had 20 extra columns. You'd need some way for each user to define what their columns are for and would really still need to define columns, at least their description, in a separate place such as the user record.

Answer (score 1):

You could place an extra column for storing string data and store an array describing the contents for custom cells. For example:

```
$custom = array(
    array("field" => "bikesOwned", "value" => 4),
    array("field" => "travelled", "value" => 14)
);
```

then use something like PHPs json_encode to store that data in the extra cell. Then all you would need to do is decode and process the array.

Answer (score 0):

Some people suggesting using the [Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) design, but before you do, please read [Bad CaRMa](http://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/), a story about an EAV-like design that nearly destroyed a company because it was unmaintainable.

To solve this better, read [How FriendFeed uses MySQL to store schema-less data](http://bret.appspot.com/entry/how-friendfeed-uses-mysql).  You can lump all the custom columns into a single BLOB, and store it that way.  Then if you want individual attributes to be searchable, create a table for that attribute, that maps values back to the customers table.

Comment: I have heard so many horor stories about eav so i'd like to stay away from eav if possible.  I just need a simple way to allow the user to create custom fields. Can you elaborate on how one would use your strategy to allow end users to add fields. Thanks.