# Dynamic Database table attributes (best practice)

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, database-design

I want to create a DVD Database (MySQL) with custom fields, that means, that the user should be able to add his own information fields to catalogue his DVDs. I just provide the required attributes, for example:

```
 - ID
 - Title
```

The user can add fields for his own use like

```
- Actors
- Year
- Genre
- Plot
- etc
```

Now, what's the best practice for this challenge? I've got some ideas:

1. Alter the table and add attributes (possible data loss)
2. Use temporary tables (less performance)

Is there a better idea?

Comment: Seems very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814627/user-defined-fields-php-mysql

Comment: Give them their own schema and let them design their own tables

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would you design your database to allow user-defined schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923778/how-would-you-design-your-database-to-allow-user-defined-schema)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try out MySQL 5.7 and its [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).

You can use this to define a semi-structured collection of user-defined attributes.

```
CREATE TABLE Dvd (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title text NOT NULL,
  attr JSON NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Dvd
SET title = 'Wonder Woman', 
    attr = '{"Actors": ["Gal Godot", "Chris Pine"],
             "Year": "2017",
             "Genre": "Action",
             "Plot": "See Captain America: The First Avenger"
            }';
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use another table that contains dvd_id, field_name, value and store all of your custom fields there. This keeps you from having to alter the table every time a new field is added or removed.

Answer (score 0):

if i were to do that task i would make a layout like

movie
move_id | title

movie_has_attribute
movie_id | attribute_id

attribute
attribute_id | name | value

like this you can get all attributes and values by the movie_id with a join statement. I hope i got your question right.